# Node.js. Как вызвать функцию из другого .js файла? TypeError ... is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

app.js:

```js
var script = require('./script');
script.testJs();
```

script.js:

```js
function testJs() {
//...
};
```

app.js и script.js лежат в одной папке. При выполнении

```js
script.testJs();
```

ошибка **TypeError**, **Message: script.testJs is not a function**. Что не так? Доп. информация: использую Visual Studio Code, jsconfig.json:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "files": [
        "~/"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

script.js

```
function testJs() {
    ...
}

module.exports = {
    testJs: testJs
};
```

app.js

```
var script = require('./script');

script.testJs();
```

с помощью require вы не импортируете что-то в локальную область видимости, а получаете содержимое объекта module.exports, заполненного в модуел, указанном в require